# Which number is the largest in this division case?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I came across this puzzling question in a coaching school exercise book for children preparing for selective high school enrolment test. I can't figure out the answer and suspect something was wrong with the question itself. Please see the question in the following picture:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? Answer is (d). 205 and 82 both leave a remainder of 1 when divided into 411. 301 and 231 both don't leave a remainder of 1 when divided into 411. So 205 is the largest number of those given that leaves a remainder of 1 when divided into 411

Comment: Thank you, Dr Xorile. In my understanding of the question, if a number (N) is divided into 411, does that mean 411 should be the quotient? Such as N / M = 411 ... 1 (remainder)? In your explanation, it seems that 411 is treated as the dividend, such as 411 / X = Y ... 1 (rem).

Comment: Correct. That's what divided *into* means.

Comment: What's correct? My understanding or your explanation? Is 411 the quotient or the dividend? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael May The problem is worded weirdly. I speak English every day, and when someone says I will **divide** a dozen eggs **into** 3 groups, how many eggs will be in each group? The answer is 4, because 12/3=4. My understanding of the problem is that 411 should be the **divisor**. N/411 = X. Which obviously doesn’t have an answer in this particular case.

Comment: **A question someone finds puzzling** is not the same thing as **a puzzle**.  This is not a puzzle, and really should be marked as off-topic rather than being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question seem ambiguous, it is supposed to mean:

> Of the given numbers, what is the largest number that divides 411 with a remainder of 1?

In which case the answer should be

> D) 205

Since

> 82 and 205 both leave remainders of 1 when dividing 411 and that 205 is the largest of the two.

Comment: **A question someone finds puzzling** is not the same thing as **a puzzle**.  This is not a puzzle, and really should be marked as off-topic rather than being answered.

Answer (score 2):

The question means that the number is among the choices, and, the number must qualify for the following requirements:

1. $411\div x$ (the number) must have a remainder of one. In other words, $411 \text{ mod } x=1$.
2. If there are multiple numbers that satisfy requirement one, chose the largest among them.

> $411\div82=5···1$, and $411\div205=2···1$, so $82$ and $205$ satisfy the first requirement. $411 \div 231=1···180$, and $411\div301=1···110$, so they don't satisfy the first requirement. $205>82$, so the answer is D. $205$

Comment: Woah. Didn't see Isaac's answer there. If Micheal sees this, please read: If $3$ is divided into $6$, the answer is $6\div3=2$.